# "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status" in Qt creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

When I compile my program, I get `ld returned 1 exit status` error. Here is the code (**main.cpp**):

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QPushButton *okayButtom = new QPushButton("Okay");

QMainWin *mainWin = new QMainWin("Say Pig!");
QHBoxLayout *Hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
QLineEdit *inputBox = new QLineEdit;


mainWin->setWindowTitle("Hello, Pig!");
Hbox->addWidget(inputBox);
Hbox->addWidget(okayButtom);

mainWin->setLayout(Hbox);
mainWin->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

and this is **widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QtGui>

class QMainWin : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
QString WinTitle;
public:
QMainWin(const QString &title, QWidget *parent = 0):WinTitle(title)
{
    this->setWindowTitle(WinTitle);
}

~QMainWin();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

I didn't use UI file, I only use cpp source file.

Comment: Can you paste everything from the "Compile Output" pane? There might be some helpful error messages in there

Comment: A tip: Never give any of your own classes a name starting with an upper-case Q followed by another uppercase letter.  This is Qt's convention and you're bound to get a name clash at some point; it's also very confusing for anyone looking at your code.

Comment: Your main problem is Q_OBJECT macros. Remove it. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- define a body for the destructor or remove the declaration ~QMainWin();
- remove the macros Q_OBJECT;
- add `QWidget(parent)` to the initializing list at the 
  constructor.

read this http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial-t4.html